# $\bigcup_{x \in G} xHx^{-1} \neq G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I could not solve it properly: $\bigcup_{x \in G} xHx^{-1} \neq G$ if $G$ is a finite group and $H$ is a proper subgroup (of $G$).

I tried to use the class equation and to create other actions to somehow prove this inequality, but nothing worked until now.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\bigcup_{x \in G} xHx^{-1}=\{xhx^{-1}|x\in G, h\in H\}\subset G $ but there are elements $g$ in $G$ that need not be written $g=xh x^{-1}$ for some $x\in G$  and $h\in H$. For example in $G=S_3$ the element $(12)$ is not conjugate to any element of $H=\mathbb Z_3=<(123)>$.

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/374078/reference-of-a-theorem-in-group-theory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The subgroup $H$ has $[G : N_G(H)]$ distinct conjugates. Each $xHx^{-1}$ has order $|H|$.

You can use these two facts to find an upper bound for the number of elements in $\bigcup_{x \in G} xHx^{-1}$.